# Host matching not working in istio gateway

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gateway, istio

I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio) to install istio and also deployed the sample `bookinfo` app.

They have the following `ingress-gateway.yml` file

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

When I do `kubectl apply -f ingress-gateway.yml`, it works perfectly fine and I can access the application on `http://<ip>/productpage`

However, if I want to access it on a specific domain e.g. `bookinfo.com`

I changed the `hosts` field in both the `gateway` and `VirtualService` section and added an entry in my `/etc/hosts` file.

So, it changed to the following

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "bookinfo.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "bookinfo.com"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

When I try to access `http://bookinfo.com/productpage`, it gives a 404 not found. What am I missing?

PS: I am using `istio1.0.5`

Comment: Istio uses `host` header to match the hosts (`authority` header for http2). Can you make sure this header is present in the request?

Comment: Usually, it is a good idea to check the logs of the ingress gateway to see what happened. `kubectl logs INGRESS-GATEWAY-POD -n istio-system`

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. Did it work before switching the host to a specific domain?

Answer (score 0):

You already set the route to the path `/productpage`, then Your destination.host in your `VirtualService` should match your `VirtualService` name in your case is "bookinfo"

Then run the curl command

```
curl -I -HHost:bookinfo.com http://$INGRESS_HOST:$INGRESS_PORT/productpage
```

Note that you use the `-H` flag to set the Host HTTP Header to “bookinfo.com”. This is needed because your ingress Gateway is configured to handle “bookinfo.com”.

Answer (score -2):

If you are doing `curl http://bookinfo.com/productpage`, it would work only if you've done hosts file entry for that ip address.

Or a better way to do is explicitly sending header in your curl request:

```
curl <ip:port>/productpage --header 'Host: bookinfo.com'
```

If you are still not able to do it, let me now.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work even after adding `host` header on the curl request or on making entry in `/etc/hosts` file.
However, it does work after I created a new cluster. I am not sure what's wrong with the original cluster.

Comment: Ah, good you got it working, 404 is generally when your request isn’t able to find downstream services. Anyways you’ve got it now (y)

Comment: I have this same issue when both the VirtualService and the Gateway hosts are set to anything but `'*'`. I have an /etc/hosts file entry set (which matches the host in the Gateway/VirtualService configs). Works great when I use the `'*'`, but nothing else. I'm using Istio 1.4.2 and I've tried re-installing it a number of times.

Comment: I am on the same boat.